# Bind Multiple SharePoint Group To Client Side People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom

I want to bind multiple SharePoint Group to Client Side People Picker Using JavaScript.

Requirement as below.

I have two SharePoint group Group 1 and Group 2. I am able to bind group 1 by sending group id to below function, but when I send group id of group 1 and group 2 then it is does not bind to both group.

Below is my code

```
function CAS_initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId, multiple, GroupId) {
    try {
        var schema = {};
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
        schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
        schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;

        if(!multiple && multiple != undefined){
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
        }
        else {
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
        }
        if (GroupId != undefined) {
                schema['SharePointGroupID'] = GroupId;
            }

        schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
        schema['Width'] = '280px';
        this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    finally {
        $('#' + peoplePickerElementId + '_TopSpan_InitialHelpText').text('Enter User Name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can bind to multiple GroupIDs. The [ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters.SharePointGroupID property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.applicationpages.clientpickerquery.clientpeoplepickerqueryparameters.sharepointgroupid.aspx) is a `System.Int32`. If you look in the GUI settings when adding a Person or Group field you are only allowed to chose one group. I could be wrong, never tried it. But an easy option could be to add multiple pickers, one pr group.

Comment: Is it possible to bind it multiple members of single group into the client-side people picker?